# how to pass values to type parameter from one function to another

Tags: postgresql

Good morning.

I have created the type with 114 parameters to pass as IN parameter to a function schemaA.func114 .

```
 do $$
    begin
    create type type_t as             ( P_mode  varchar,
                                        p_env   VARCHAR,
                                        p_log   VARCHAR,
                                        p_method  VARCHAR,
                                        P_p1    VARCHAR,
                                        P_p2    VARCHAR,
                                        .
                                        .
                                        P_p114  NUMERIC);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN duplicate_object THEN null;
    END $$;
```

The function schemaA.func114 is having 114 parameters as same as type "type_t".
The function schemaB.func110 is having 110 parameters.It's having same parameters as type "type_t" except the following four extra parameters.

```
P_mode
p_env
p_log
p_method


create or replace  function schemaA.func114(p_type_parmaters type_t)
RETURNS void AS
$$
declare
  begin
  raise notice 'func114 called';

perform schemaB.func110(P_p1    VARCHAR,
                        P_p2    VARCHAR,
                                        .
                                        .
                        P_p110  NUMERIC);

raise notice 'func110 called';                         
end $$ language plpgsql;
```

I need help in the following.

How to pass values to pramter "p_type_parmaters" for schemaA.func114 function.
How to create type for schemaB.func110.
How to pass values to pramters for schemaB.func110 function from schemaA.func114 function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just spell out the 110 arguments.

Comment: I need help in the following.

How to pass values to pramter "p_type_parmaters" for schemaA.func114 function. How to create type for schemaB.func110. How to pass values to pramters for schemaB.func110 function from schemaA.func114 function.